# What should I write in the post action of this front end post form?

Tags: php, forms

I'm following [this](http://wpshout.com/wordpress-submit-posts-from-frontend/) tutorial to build a front end form:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * New Post Form for Custom Post Types for the Frontend of Your Site
 * By Jared Williams - http://new2wp.com
 *
 * Last Updated: 8/30/2010
 */

// Check if the form was submitted
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['title'])) { 
        $title =  $_POST['title']; 
    } else { 
        echo 'Please enter a title';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) { 
        $description = $_POST['description']; 
    } else { 
        echo 'Please enter the content'; 
    }
    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_category' => $_POST['cat'],  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
        'tags_input'    => $tags, 
        'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, etc.
        'post_type'     => $_POST['post_type']  // Use a custom post type if you want to
    );
    wp_insert_post($post);  // Pass  the value of $post to WordPress the insert function
                            // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); // redirect to home page after submit

} // end IF
// Do the wp_insert_post action to insert it
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post'); 
?>

<!-- New Post Form -->
<div id="postbox">
    <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="">
        <p><label for="title">Title</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title" />
        </p>
        <p><label for="description">Description</label><br />
        <textarea id="description" tabindex="3" name="description" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=category' ); ?></p>
        <p><label for="post_tags">Tags</label>
            <input type="text" value="" tabindex="5" size="16" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" /></p>
        <p align="right"><input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>

        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="post" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
    </form>
</div>
<!--// New Post Form -->
```

Right now the action part:

```
    <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="">
```

Is empty

I tried two things:

I tried placing the the whole code in a file called page-submit.php.
I'm getting this:

> It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching, or
>   one of the links below, can help.

I also tried placing the php part in a file called frontpost.php.
and adding this:

```
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/frontpost.php">
```

to the action. But I get a Server Error.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: You've added a nonce field, but you haven't checked it! You should check the nonce-field immediately after the action has been checked and only proceed if its correct.

Comment: how about leaving it empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your processing form a template and apply it to a page if you want wordpress to recognize the form. Then you can set your action to the name of the page with the template applied to it and viola!